# Replace value in string with another from another string

Tags: c, arrays, string, replace

I've been stuck for a while now. The program i'm writing basically changes the false words with the correct ones from the dictionary. However, when i run the program, it gives me no warnings or errors, but it doesn't display anything. Can you please help me?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<ctype.h>
 #include<string.h>

int main(void){
char fname[20],word[2500], dictn[50];
int i,j;
float len1, len2;
FILE *inp, *dict, *outp, *fopen();
fpos_t pos1, pos2;

dict= fopen("dictionary.txt", "r"); 
printf("Enter the path of the file you want to check:\n");
scanf("%s", fname);
inp= fopen(fname, "r");

for(i=0;(fscanf(inp, "%s", word) != EOF); i++){ 
for(j=0;fscanf(dict, "%s", dictn) != EOF; j++){

fgetpos(inp, &pos1);
fgetpos(dictn, &pos2);

len1=(float)strlen(word);
len2=(float) strlen(dictn);

if(len1<=(0.6*len2)){
    fsetpos(dictn, &pos1);

    }

if(strncmp(word, dictn, 1)==0){ 
    fsetpos(dictn, &pos1);  
    
    }
 
if(strcmp(word, dictn)==0){
    fsetpos(dictn, &pos1);

}
    
}

    printf("%s ", word);

}

fclose(inp);

fclose(dict);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: You're saying the problem is that when you have the code you want to use, the code doesn't compile. Don't you think it would be a super idea to provide the code that doesn't compile, along with the error output provided when compilation is attempted?

Comment: Sorry, i added the other part. This is my first time using this website.

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to compile? You're going to have a problem as well when it comes to copying strings, `word[i]=dictn[j]` is only going to assign pointers, not copy the actual characters in the word.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: If `word` and `dictn` are both arrays of `char` then I can't see how the `strncmp` and `strcmp` calls work here. `strncmp(word, dictn, 1)` will compare the first character of both words. If it returns something other than 0, it means the first character is different. When that happens, I don't see how `strcmp(word, dictn)` could possibly return 0.

Comment: Can you clarify how you can tell whether `word` needs to be replaced by `dictn`? The logic of the program doesn't seem to make much sense here.

Comment: Well, the program takes a file, stores it in a string (in this case it's word). Then it takes a dictionary from a file (in this case dictn). Then, it should compare each word from the file with the ones in the dictionary. If the words both begin with the same letter, have the same number of characters or 60% of the same letters in common, then that particular word from the input file, must be replaced with the correct one from the dictionary. It's mainly a spell checker.

Comment: I already have both files of the text and the dictionary, what i have a problem with, is the point where i have to replace to false word with thee correct one from the dictionary. When i run the program nothing happens, it doesn't display any warnings or errors. So can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sprintf(word, "%s ", dictn);
```

If your code is working with printf it should work with sprintf, provided you don't overflow "word", including the NULL termination, so you might have to resize "word" if it is smaller than dictn.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that! But can you please explain more what does   sprintf do? Is it the same as  fprintf ?

Comment: sprintf works like printf, but it prints to a character string instead of standard output (in the example prints to the string named "word"). It would be good to see the declaration of "word" and "dictn". The safest way to handle the problem you have would be reading character by character looking for blank spaces, tabs or new line characters, because the way you are reading from the file has the potential to overflow "word" or "dictn" if the user feeds your program a text file with a very long uninterrupted sequence of characters and your program would crash or have some random behaviour

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm assuming you have created arrays `word` and `dictn` with enough size to hold the maximum length string any of your files.

**First fault:**

In loops you've created, `i` represents number of strings in input file and `j` represents number of strings in dictionary. `word` is your input string variable and `dictn` is your dictionary string variable. But you want to retrieve and alter word's ith or dictn's jth character. This may cause an error because there can be a case like this:

Suppose there are 10 words at `inp` file and 100 words at `dictn`. And in your loops, `i` have value of 8 and `j` have value of 88. Corresponding these `i` and `j` values, word has string value of, say, `apple` and `dictn` has string value of `apple` also. So this means `apple` is the 8th word at input file and 88th word at dictionary file. And if one of those if conditions was satisfied, compiler tries to apply a statement like `word[i]=dictn[j];`. This means `word[8] = dictn[88];` for this example. But both of those string have `apple` as values which consists only 5 characters! And this will cause an error since you've tried to retrieve 88th character of a 5-length string and assign it to the 8th character of a 5-length string. So your code is wrong, it will only work for some cases which will be a rare situation.

**Second fault:**

I assume you want to read whole dictionary file for every word in input file but you will be able to read it for only first word of input file since you don't reopen it or set position indicator at the beginning of dictionary file after you read whole dictionary.

**Third fault:**

Your first if statement will never be reached assuming you have created `len1` and `len2` variables as integers. Because in your if statement, there is a multiplication of a decimal number and an integer which will return 0 as a result and since `fscanf()` ignores whitespaces, `len1` and `len2` will be at least 1.

**Fourth fault:**

Also your `else if` statement will never be reached because if a string has same value with another, their first character will also be equal to each other and your if statement where you compare their first characters will be also accepted.

---

Actually, I would write a code as solution but first of all you need to correct things up which are logically wrong because I do not know what you are really try to achieve by your code -just because I commented with full of assumptions-. But I can provide you some guidelines:

1. Convert your `len1` and `len2` variables from `int` to `float` and cast values which return from `strlen()` functions to `float`.
2. Reopen your `dict` file for every iteration of outside loop. (And do not forget not to close it).
3. To change your `inp` file, you can use a `fpos_t` type of variable to track your position indicator of your `inp` file (`fgetpos()` to get current position and `fsetpos()` to change position with value of `fpos_t` variable. You can search them.) and type the word with `fprintf()` or `fputs()` to that location to change that string.